# Fetch Cursor again from DB on back button press (For updated listview)

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-cursor

I am dealing with a ListFragment (A) which shows a listview (using a Cursor) and on item click a new activity (B) is opened which shows details pertaining to that item.

The problem I am facing is when changes are made to the single item and back button is pressed i.e we go back to the listview, the changes aren't reflected there. Now, I understand that the cursor is still working with the old dataset and fetching database again would solve this issue. However, I am not able to implement this. I tried overriding the `onResume()` method but for some reason that method is being called when A is first created as well as when back button is pressed.

Following class in A is responsible for fetching the data set in Cursor:

```
private class LoadWordList extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Cursor> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        progressDialog.setTitle("Loading");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait while the word list loads...");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Cursor doInBackground(String... strings) {

        //Step 2
        db = new MyDatabase(getActivity());
        wordsList = db.getWords();
        return wordsList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Cursor cursor) {
        //Step 3
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, cursor,
                new String[]{"word"}, new int[]{android.R.id.text1});

        //Step 4
        getListView().setAdapter(adapter);

        if (progressDialog != null) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you using loaders?

Comment: No, I am not. Just the cursor object.

Comment: what flags to CursorAdapter ctor are you using?